# Nodejs API can’t be reached via linux server

Tags: node.js, linux, google-cloud-platform, deployment, nodejs-server

I am using google cloud linux to deploy my nodejs app, I follow this tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxoGv_vogdc, every steps going well without error.

However when I enter API url like this `IP:port/home`, the url keep loading for a while and then showing: `This site can’t be reached. (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)`

I research google and try to work around like changing to different ports, restart the service...etc

I also test my nodejs app again, it working in my PC and on Render service. I realized that in the `Youtube` video, he skipped 2 minutes before he showing his website working.

I guess that I am missing some important steps to make my site running.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, I mistaken when naming pm2 project. The pm2 project name must be matched with the name of project pulls from `Github`

Example: If project from Github name: `node-api-project`, then name of pm2 project must be like this: `pm2 start npm --name "node-api-project" -- start`